# How word2vect algorithm works using a neural network

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, word-embeddings, word2vec

Can anyone provide information as to how a word2vec algorithm works using a neural network.
(An easy example to understand it with formulas please.)

Comment: What is it exactly that you're looking for? How a neural network is used in word2vec to create embeddings or how to use word2vec embeddings as inputs in a neural network? If it is the first have a look at [the following page](https://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-word2vec/).

Answer (score 0):

you can visit the Andrew Ng course  he provides details about mathematical formulas

or you can visit the following link, and have the example on the Kaggle data set with all the notes from his course.

[link](https://www.kaggle.com/code/abdulbasitniazi/word2vec-glove-a-beginner-s-guide)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).